# Plot Confusion Matrix with custom x and y axis in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have confusion matrix in form of an array like

```
[[ 265, 1522],
 [  44,  146]]
```

I am doing something like this to plot

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
cm = confusion_matrix(yTest, yPredicted)
sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True,fmt="d", cmap='YlGnBu', linecolor='black', linewidths=1)
plt.title("Confusion Matrix")
plt.title("Confusion Matrix")
plt.xlabel("Actual")
plt.ylabel("Predicted")
```

and[image: it is giving me this graph]

But How can i change x and y axsis and get graph like that
[image: Required Graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transpose the matrix, swap the axis labels and reverse the axis directions by setting the limits:

```
sns.heatmap(cm.T, annot=True,fmt="d", cmap='YlGnBu', linecolor='black', linewidths=1)
plt.title("Confusion Matrix")
plt.ylabel("Actual")
plt.xlabel("Predicted")
plt.ylim(0,2)
plt.xlim(2,0)
```

You can rotate y axis labels as shown in your example like that:

```
plt.ylabel('\n'.join(list('Actual')), rotation=0, va='center')
plt.yticks(rotation=0)
```

[image]